# How to stop android app opening from push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to stop my Android App opening automatically when I click on the PUSH Notification send via Google FCM. I have changed the message type from Data Message to Notification message.
The PUSH I am sending via the server REST API has a promo code in it, but has nothing to do with my App really, so I dont want the Android App to open at all. I can't used the FCM Console to send the PUSH notification as each promo code is unique to the user and their pet, and there are thousands of them.  I'm using the test http v1. api but the actual Android App has been built by someone else and I dont have access to the source code.  What should I be looking out for ?  Is the PUSH auto opening the App due to a call it makes and an intent in the app I can't change?
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Have you used click_action in notification object?

Comment: No - I am using apace/httpclient-4.5.jar and targetting FCM API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Should I be using a click on action to STOP the App opening ?